# Save web data into PostGIS

Tags: postgis, php

Is it possible to store harvested data from a website(Nestoria) upon implementing their APIs using PHP?
I am able to extract the data using PHP and it displays the result on a web browser, but I need to dump or save them into my PostGIS database. (I am using XAMPP and PostGIS on windows 7)

Comment: Do you have permission to scrape Nestoria's data?

Comment: @Mapperz: As long as akinboj abides by "The legal details" on http://www.nestoria.co.uk/help/api I can't see why not.

Comment: I would be inclined to say this is a question more suited to StackOverflow because it's really about scraping and storing data in general, rather than about GIS. If you're having problems storing geospatial data after you have got the non-geospatial part sorted, then feel free to ask another question.

Comment: You can access the Data via the Nestoria API but need to be careful - they have this clause 'The data must not be indexable by search engines.' so most websites are index-able - they are protecting their own website. This is easy to infringe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most companies wouldn't have a problem with you doing that, for instance Ebay's API. However, as Mapperz pointed out - Nestoria's terms require you not to compete with them for originality of the content. So, any data that comes from their API and stored in your database should not be able to be indexed by search engines.

This isn't as difficult to comply with as you might think. You could have the content loaded through an iframe that uses the "NoIndex, NoFollow" meta tag attribute in the HTML of the page being loaded, or pull the content from the database to your page's DOM using AJAX/JavaScript after the page has loaded.

I personally would go with the second option (AJAX).

Comment: @ Rexbit, Mapperz; I should have mentioned that I am only using it for academic purposes, so I need not worry about their terms. The fact is that I am still unable to dump the results into my database after the page has loaded. Any further help?